# Настроить fail2ban с phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, fail2ban

Настраиваю **fail2ban**. Чтобы предотвратить брутфорс, пытаюсь подкрутить сюда же и **phpMyAdmin**. Но нигде не могу найти, как подключить его логирование. Буду благодарен за любую информацию. Сервер на CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin - это обычное веб приложение. и все, что относится к вопросам доступа к нему будет попадать в соответствующие логи apache. поэтому, либо просто разбираетесь с реакцией на ошибки апача, либо пишете собственные правила анализируя при этом лог именно апача.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin пишет лог в `/var/log/secure`, соответственно, очень легко его запарсить.

1. Создаем фильтр с именем файла `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf`
   и содержимым:

   `before = common.conf
   [Definition]
   _daemon = (?:phpMyAdmin)
   failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)suser denied: .* \(mysql-denied\) from <HOST>$
   ignoreregex =`
2. В файл джейла дописываем `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

   `[phpmyadmin]
    enabled  = true
    filter   = phpmyadmin
    port     = https
    action   = iptables-multiport[name=phpMyAdmin, port=http, protocol=tcp]
               sendmail-whois[name=phpMyAdmin, dest=you@email.com]
    logpath  = /var/log/secure
    findtime    = 3600
    maxretry = 5
    bantime  = 2592000`

Если у вас еще стоит Vesta CP, то в action новой строкой можно добавить

```
vesta[name=PHPMYADMIN]
```

Answer (score 0):

fail2ban не умеет следить за phpMyAdmin

Comment: Это не является ответом на вопрос. Больше похоже на комментарий.